# $.fn.plugin with chaining and callback

Tags: jquery, callback, chaining

I have written a Jquery plugin called mass. I learned that it chains nicely by putting 'return this' right at the end.

```
$('.thing').mass(0.5,500).draggable();
```

but how can I give it a callback without hurting the chaining?

the code would look like:

```
$('.thing').mass(0.5,500,function(){/*do some stuff*/}).draggable();
```

My plugin might as well just be shown as to save confusion and extra irrelevant code:

```
$.fn.mass=function(options,callback){/*do stuff*/return this;}
```

I am not sure after reading examples if I have the correct understanding. If you .call() the callback then how do you go back into the original function to 'return this' to the chain or how do you pass this to the callback callback(this) and tell it to 'return this' when done?

I am missing something here? I think callback(this) is the way to go but, I don't want to have to write return this inside every time like so:

```
$('.thing').mass(0.5,500,function(){/*do some stuff*/return this;}).draggable();
```

Comment: Callback functions are executed *later*. They have nothing to do with current chain. They can do whatever you want.

Comment: right!? O.o I was also thinking of something like return [this,callback]. **When later after the chain??**

Comment: The concept of callback is: "when you're finished doing X, please run this function". Passing a function reference as argument does not execute the function inmediately and does not block the page. That's the whole point.

Comment: can you make an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Well, I'm still not 100% sure of what the question is but I'll try xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
$.fn.plugin = function(a, b, callback) {
  // save reference to `this` as `that`
  var that = this;
  // change context of `callback` to `$(this)`
  var proxy = (callback != undefined 
              ? $.proxy(typeof callback === "function" 
                ? callback 
                : $.noop(), $(this)) 
              : $.noop());
  var a = a || null;
  var b = b || null;
  // do stuff
  $(this).append(a * b);
  console.log(a, b);
  // return `$(this)` , as `$(that)` , chainable
  return $.when(proxy()).promise($(that));
};
$("#proxy").plugin(Math.PI, 123, function() { 
   // `log` `id` of `$(this)` object , i.e., `$(this) === $(that)` ,
   // returned `deferred.promise` object 
   console.log($(this)[0].id)}) // `proxy`
   .css("color", "green");
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/JKrc4/

See

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Answer (score 1):

As your concerns illustrate, a decent jQuery plug-in should be a good team player and not kill the chain. That means:

- It should return a `jQuery` object so you're able to apply more method calls afterwards.
- It should work on the original collection of matched elements and pass it to the next method call, either unaltered or with the appropriate modifications (as documented and dictated by the plug-in functionality).

Things not to do:

- Ignore matched elements and run your own selections from scratch
- Destroy the element collection for no good reason (e.g., for returning a new jQuery object inadvertently rather than the original one).

What role do callback functions play here? Absolutely none.

Though I'm not fully sure of what the concern is, a common misconception is not distinguising between function references and function calls. E.g., given this function:

```
function add(a, b){
    return a+b;
}
```

This is a function call:

```
foo(add(3+5));
```

`add()` runs immediately, returns 8 and passes 8 to `foo()`. However, this is a function reference:

```
foo(add);
```

`add()` does not run. It simply get passed to `foo()`, which can decide at a later stage what to do with it.

To sum up, when you do something like this:

```
$('.thing').mass(0.5,500,function(){/*do some stuff*/}).draggable();
```

... the `/*do some stuff*/` bit does not run and does not have any effect on the chain. Later, you can chose to run it, but it can possibly be long after `.draggable()` did its magic.